# What is the function of "du dich"?

Tags: accusative, reflexive

> Kannst du dich bitte darum kümmern?

Since it is literary translated as:

“can you you please about-it to take-care?”

I was wondering what the function of *dich* here is?

Comment: [Translate "dich" as "yourself"](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/yourself) here and the translation is almost literal: "Can you please take care of it yourself?" Only word order is different.

Comment: @Roland not 100% sure, but this english phrase sounds slightly rude/annoyed to me, while the german one is neutral.

Comment: @lalala That's probably because English people appreciate directness less than Germans. Also, the German phrase can be slightly rude, it depends on how you stress the words. But I admit, this literal translation has a different tone, because English doesn't need a reflexive pronoun here and thus including "yourself" slightly alters the meaning (it puts more emphasis on "dich", wich in German we would do with "dich selbst").

Comment: @Roland using yourself to translate dich for a reflexive verb seems wrong. It should just be dropped if the translated verb isn't reflexive, imo.

Comment: @kutschkem I don't disagree. OP referred to a literal translation. And if you do that, "yourself" is a better translation for the reflexive "dich" than "you".

Answer (score 8):

"Sich kümmern" is a reflexive verb, and therefore is conjugated as "du kümmerst dich" in the second person. The order of words in your case is different due to the sentence structure for questions in German. For a conjugation of reflexive verbs see [this resource for more information.](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/reflexive-verben.html)
[This resource](https://www.deutsch-perfekt.com/deutsch-ueben/reflexive-verben) provides some more insight into reflexive verbs used in questions.

Comment: @userunknown Mein Duden (25. Auflage) widerspricht dir da. Unter Regel K 96 wird ausgeführt, dass eine Kleinschreibung in diesem Falle möglich (nicht aber vorgeschrieben) ist. Dort heißt es: „Ein mit Anführungszeichen oder anderer Schriftart gekennzeichnetes zitiertes Wort bleibt ebenfalls häufig unverändert.“ (Das „ebenfalls“ bezieht sich auf zuvor angeführte Sätze, die nach Apostroph oder Auslassungspunkten mit Kleinbuchstaben beginnen.) Als Beispiele werden folgende zwei Sätze angeführt:

„von“ ist eine Präposition.
*dass* wurde früher mit ß geschrieben.

Comment: @mdomino: Stimmt, interessant! "sich" wird als Wort nun mal klein geschrieben, außer wenn es am Satzanfang steht, es sei denn, es ist mit Anführungszeichen gekennzeichnet und es geht gerade um die Groß- und Kleinschreibung ;-).

Comment: @mdomino: Diese angebliche Regel des Dudens ist ein beklagenswertes Beispiel seiner Schwäche. Was soll das für eine Regel sein: "bleibt häufig unverändert"? Soll ich jetzt eine Strichliste führen und in 3 von 5 Fällen das erste Wort klein schreiben? Das ist keine Regel, sondern ein empirischer Befund. Welche Funktion hat denn die Großschreibung am Satzanfang? Schreibregeln haben generell nur eine Funktion: Sie sollen das Lesen erleichtern. Nicht das Schreiben, sondern das Lesen, denn 1x geschriebenes wird i.d.R. nur 1x geschrieben, aber oft dutzend- oder zigtausendfach gelesen. …

Comment: … Eine Kleinschreibung am Satzanfang bringt aber jeden Leser ins Schlingern und ist daher kontraproduktiv. Das soll ja tunlichst vermieden werden, dass der Leser zögert und innehalten muss, aus dem Lesefluss kommt, weil er erst nachdenken muss, was hier der Grund für Kleinschreibung ist  (um dann ohnehin alle denkbaren, sinnvollen Gründe zu verwerfen und bei "Pseudoakkuratesse" zu landen). Es ist auch kein Zitat, wenn es nur ein Wort ist, sondern Metasprache. Das Von, Und, Dass werden ja nicht einem konkreten Text entnommen, oder wenn, dann ist dieser nur ein Beispiel und in einem anderen …

Comment: … Beispiel könnten die Wörter auch genausogut am Satzanfang stehen, und dem Zitatgedanken nach dann doch gerade wieder groß geschrieben werden müssen, wenn Zitattreue das wahre Motiv wäre. Hier im Text war im Orginal von "sich" nicht die Rede, sondern von "dich", womit gezeigt ist, dass es sich gerade nicht um Zitate handelt. Dass die Wortfunktion den Satzanfang sticht, scheidet als Begründung aber besonders aus, denn auf die Wortfunktion wird ja sonst am Satzanfang auch nie Rücksicht genommen. Dazu kommt, dass in Metasprache die Funktion des Wortes ja gerade verloren ist, und "von, das, und"…

Comment: … wie Substantive benutzt werden: Beispiel: Das "das" in dem Satz muss großgeschrieben werden. Das zweite "das" bekommt einen Artikel und wird wie ein Substantiv verwendet. (Ginge es nach mir, würde man es deshalb großschreiben sollen). Als vorläufig letzter Punkt, der hier nicht so relevant ist, weil es meist am Absatzbeginn vorkommt führe ich an, dass eine Kleinschreibung nach einem Punkt dazu führt, dass man das Wort davor als Abkürzung wahrnimmt. Das ist aber durch die Zeichenfolge vor dem Punkt, so es überhaupt einen und eine solche gibt, oft raschh auszuschließen.

Comment: @userunknown Mag ja sein, dass das, was der Duden als Zitat bezeichnet besser als „Metasprache“ bezeichnet wird, das ändert aber nichts an der Sache. Die vom Duden angeführten Beispiele sind ebenfalls keine Zitate in dem Sinne, also greift die Aussage des Dudens hier dennoch. Du schreibst in deinem Kommentar: „Sätze beginnen immer mit Großbuchstaben“. Auch da könnte ich nun sagen, das ist keine Regel, sondern ein empirischer Befund, zudem ein falscher. Es ist aber nicht mal eine Regel, da die Duden-Regel D 96 mitsamt ihrer Beispiele dir da widerspricht. Hier auch noch mal online nachzulesen:

Comment: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D96 Bei der Frage, ob der Einsatz des Kleinbuchstaben hier kontraproduktiv ist, würde ich dir ebenfalls widersprechen. Gerade für Fremdsprachler mag es an dieser Stelle von Vorteil sein, nicht darüber nachdenken zu müssen, ob das „Sich“ an dieser Stelle nur deshalb groß geschrieben ist, weil es am Satzanfang steht oder weil es ein eigenes, großgeschriebenes Wort namens „Sich“ ist.

Comment: @mdomino: Wenn es keine Zitate in dem Sinne sind - von welchem Sinne redest Du? In welchem Sinne sonst sind es denn Zitate? Ich hatte keinen Zitatsinn eingegrenzt, sondern behaupte es sind keine Zitate - Punkt. Also sind es nun Zitate oder nicht? Du eierst da rum, willst am Wort festhalten, obwohl Du den Sinn des Wortes zu opfern bereit bist. In direkter Rede wird der Satzanfang auch groß geschrieben, so dass die Anführungszeichen alleine nicht tragen. Text in anderen Schriftarten genießen auch keine Extrabehandlung, also was soll der Grund sein, die Großschreibung zu suspendieren?

Comment: Deine Argumentation ist übrigens tautologisch. Du sagst, man schreibt es klein weil es der Duden sagt, und der Duden sagt es, wie man nachlesen kann, also muss es stimmen. Außerdem schließt Du bei Deinem imaginierten Fremdsprachler in die falsche Richtung: Du gehst davon aus, dass dieser Schwierigkeiten mit einem großen "Sich" am Satzanfang haben müsste - ohne jede Evidenz und gegen jede vernünftige Annahme, und leitest daraus ein Adhocgebot ab, kleinzuschreiben. Weder schreibt man für Fremdsprachler anders  und falsch, damit sie es einfacher haben, noch hätten sie es dadurch einfacher, …

Comment: @userunknown Es ist kein Zitat. Die vom Duden gebrachten Beispiele für eine mögliche Kleinschreibung am Satzanfang sind aber ebenfalls keine Zitate. Der Grund die Großschreibung zu suspendieren ist, dass es laut Duden erlaubt ist und im meiner Meinung nach vorliegenen Fall eine größere Eindeutigkeit schafft, da man als Fremdsprachler genau weiß, wie das Wort im Normalfall geschrieben wird.

Comment: …, sondern im Gegenteil. Statt einer einfachen Regel hätte man eine Ausnahme von der Ausnahme zu lernen, die weder Sinn macht, noch irgendwelchen Erwartungen entgegenkommt. Alle Sprachen mit lateinischem Alphabet, die ich kenne, schreiben am Satzanfang groß. Wieso sollte sich da jemand fragen, wieso "sich" am Satzanfang groß geschrieben wird? Die Prämisse ist schon bizarr falsch.

Comment: Die Evidenz, dass etwas geändert werden muss, bringst du selbst nicht. Du schreibst nur, dass Leser ins Schlingern geraten, was du ebensowenig beweisen kannst. Es hat keiner etwas falsch geschrieben, du behauptest das aber weiterhin und lieferst keinen Beweis. Nach welcher sprachlichen Instanz sollen wir uns denn deiner Meinung nach richten? Nach dem Duden, der nach allgemeiner Konvention die Orthografie der deutschen Sprache in ein Regelwerk fasst, oder nach deiner, userunknown's, eigenen Konvention, deren Regeln wir dann hier antizipieren sollen?

Comment: [§54 der amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6162) ist ziemlich eindeutig.